# Material Design Styles Not Shown Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, android-design-library

I created a blank Android Application with no activities.
I added the dependence for design library in the 'build.gradle'
Then I rebuilt the project and I went to the only styles.xml that I have, and I can't refer to Material styles.
How can I do? Is there a better way?
Thanks

Comment: You mean like `parent="Theme.AppCompat"`?

Comment: Exactly, I only have the AppCompat ones

Comment: As far as I know, the Material themes are part of the SDK that is compiled with, not the support design library.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm compiling with 24.0.3 (it chose it by default)

Comment: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material"` should work.... https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html

Comment: `minSdk` does need to be 21 or higher, though

Comment: I'll check in a few hours but I'm sure that android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material" doesn't work

Comment: @cricket_007 The minSdk is 24

Comment: @cricket_007 no, sorry, The minSdk was 15, I change it to 21. But I want users with android 4 to be able to use my app, how can I do?

Comment: Well I actually rebuild the project with minSdk = 21, but I couldn't use the Material themes anyway

Comment: Can you add your Gradle file to the question, please?

Comment: I actually deleted the project and I have created a new one with a navigation bar, which has added by its own all the required files, is it correct? @cricket_007

Comment: I have no idea. I never use any of the templates or auto generated code because it doesn't really help me learn and there's often way too much code that's necessary for what I want the app to do

Comment: Yeah, I know, thank you so much for your help! I think I'll "see" you soon in another question because I can't do anything with Android Studio and I'm even new to Java, so...